# Unlimited nested ngFor through child items

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I found a couple of questions about nested ngFor loops in Angular2 but not what i'm looking for. I want to show categories in a list. My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    Categories: [{
        "Title": "Categorie A",
        "Children": [ 
            {
                "Title": "Sub Categorie A",
                "Children": []
            }
        ]
    },{
        "Title": "Categorie B",
        "Children": [ 
            {
                "Title": "Sub Categorie B",
                "Children": [{
                    "Title": "Sub Sub Categorie A",
                    "Children": []
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

C# class looks like this:

```
public class Child
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<object> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now the trick is to get this in a ngFor loop without any restrictions on the depth of children.

Comment: Why not write a component that renders another of the same component as a sub component for each child? Then it just takes an object with a Title and zero or more Children as an input and only renders a single level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would be pretty straightforward with a component that renders itself as child elements:

```ts
export interface Category {
  Title: string;
  Children: Category[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-category',
  template: `
    <h2>{{ category.Title }}</h2>
    <ul *ngIf="category.Children.length > 0">
      <li *ngFor="let child of category.Children">
        <my-category [category]="child"></my-category>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class MyCategoryComponent {
  @Input() category: Category;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is definitely easier then I thought.

Comment: Just created a plunker to test it. 
For people who are interested in a working demo. It can be found on: https://plnkr.co/edit/4nRdPrLGcDXVubVYe0ux

Comment: @ChristiaanMolendijk neat; I've added in list elements to make the structure clearer

Comment: @jonsharpe thanks, that makes it much clearer. I've updated the plunker.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for this solutions. one more question I have. If I want to get the value from every tree view after click on the child tree view, how can I get it? I am doing something like this below but it's showing all list from parent of tree

`
<h2>{{ category!.Title }}</h2>
<ul *ngIf="category!.Children.length > 0">
    <li style="margin-left: 20px;" *ngFor="let child of category!.Children" (click)="showVal(child, $event)">
        <b>B</b> <app-tree-view-folder [category]="child"></app-tree-view-folder>
    </li>
</ul>
`
Please see the next comment for more ...

Comment: In ts file:

`
  showVal(data:any, e:any){
    console.log(data);
    this.clickOutside.emit(data);
    // e.stopPropagation();
  }
`
Where using :
`
<app-tree-view-folder
  [category]="category"
  (clickOutside)="getCurrentData($event)">
</app-tree-view-folder>
`

In TS file:
`
  getCurrentData(data:any){
    console.log(data);
  }
`

Hopefully some one have a good solution